# Чем в С++ объект класса отличается от самого класса?

Tags: c++

Чем в С++ объект класса отличается от самого класса?

Comment: Чем рецепт торта отличается от торта? Чем чертёж машины отличается от автомобиля?

Comment: Например пишешь `std::vector<int> data;`. `std::vector` это класс, `data` - объект класса.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко , к вашему комментарию небольшая поправка - `std::vector` это не класс, а шаблон класса, классом в данном примере является его инстанс `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: обьект   занимает место, имеет свою  роль в кодах...  Класс описывает с чего  сделан каждый такой обьект, каким он будет:  как может создаваться этот обьект, какое место(память) займет,  как может себя вести и т.д и т.п.

Comment: @ArtikSlayer Скорее наоборот, объект класса - это торт, а класс - это рецепт торта.

Comment: @VTT,  никто не утверждал обратное, но я бы не сделал такое сравнение: рецепт торта  не описывет  поведение торта, его состояние, срок хранения и т.д., а чертеж машины не описывет какие действия может совершить машина и как взоимодействуют узлы и детали

Comment: @VTT Да, вы правы.

Comment: Тем же, чем любая переменная отличается от своего типа. Вопрос "чем в `int i;` переменная `i` отличается от типа `int`?" не встает?

Comment: @zcorvid, всегда называл `std::vector` не шаблоном класса, а шаблонным класом. А `std::vector<int>` просто классом. Но тут уже, видимо, как где принято.

Answer (score 1):

### Если очень примитивно: класс это описание, идентификатор типа, объект (экземпляр) класса это переменная.

По аналогии с типами, если мы пишем `int x;`, то здесь `int` это "класс", а `x` - объект класса.

Пример чуть сложнее.

```
class Point
{
public:
    double x;
    double y;
}

int main()
{
    Point A;
    return 0;
}
```

Здесь `Point` - класс, а `A` в функции `main` - объект класса.

Ещё один пример.

```
std::vector<int> data;
```

Здесь `data` - объект класса, а `std::vector<int>` - класс (а `std::vector` - шаблон класса, но это уже другая история.)

Answer (score 0):

Класс — абстрактное понятие. Объект класса — конкретный объект. Например, есть у Вас класс `modern_transport`, в котором поля, допустим, количество колес, тип двигателя, его объем, мощность и т.д.

И есть два объекта этого класса: `car` и `motocicle`.

У `car` кол-во колес будет равно 4, тип двигателя: бензиновый, свой объем двигателя, мощность и т. д.

У `motocicle`соответственно два колеса и т.д.

В итоге мы будем иметь две переменные одного типа, но с разными значениями.

Если провести аналогию с примитивами, то  `int` — какое-то абстрактное целое число, а `int number =12;` уже конкретная переменная со значением 12.

Примерно так же дело обстоит и с классом и объектом класса.

Класс = способ организации полей, методов и пр. = инкапсулированный «кусок» функциональности, описание структуры будущих объектов + своё пространство имён внутри.

Объект = экземпляр класса = объект, типом которого является какой-то класс = класс после инициализации = сущность в памяти, обладающая поведением, способная изменять своё состояние.

Comment: Класс - это абстрактное понятие? `class A { public: A() = default; int a; }` . Это очень абстрактно? Может вы имели ввиду, что класс это описания свойств и поведения неких объектов? Только это не абстрактное понятие.  Кроме этого класс это тот же тип данных, только клиентский. То есть int = double = client_type = data type. Получается все типы данных это абстрактные понятия?